# Android Multiple Row Number in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I Want a GridView that First Item is in Single Column and The Rest are in Two Column.
how can I Implement That?
In my Purpose I Can't use GridLayout.
Many Thanks

Like this : http://upload7.ir/viewer.php?file=10724303115268881323.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by custom gridview implementation witch support `headers` 
:

https://github.com/munix/GridViewHeader

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to achive that. What you can do is using listview with an header and handling the grid visualization by yourself.

Do you need these items to be visible?

Comment: i have many of these items. these are my blog posts. the very first item should be alone in the row!